# Cannot format Timespan on Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ComboBox` which `ItemsSource` is `List<TimeSpan>`. I tried to set the `ItemStringFormat` property in order to format the time as "13:25" instead of "13:25:00", however, all I get is empty items.

I tried

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" ItemStringFormat="hh\\:mm"/>
```

I also tried

```
ItemStringFormat="hh:mm"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the format that you are looking for:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
          ItemStringFormat="{}{0:hh}:{0:mm}" />
```